# Increment Serial Number using EXIF

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, exif, exiftool

I am using ExifTool to change the camera body serial number to be a unique serial number for each image in a group of images numbering several hundred.  The camera body serial number is being used as a second place, in addition to where the serial number for the image is in IPTC, to put the serial number as it takes a little more effort to remove.

The serial number is in the format ###-###-####-#### where the last four digits is the number to increment.  The first three groups of digits do not change for each batch I run.  I only need to increment that last group of digits.

**EXAMPLE**
I if I have 100 images in my first batch, they would be numbered:

811-010-5469-0001, 811-010-5469-0002, 811-010-5469-0003 ... 811-010-5469-0100

I can successfully drag a group of images onto my ExifTool Shortcut that has the values

```
exiftool(-SerialNumber='001-001-0001-0001')
```

and it will change the Exif SerialNumber Tag on the images, but have not been successful in what to add to this to have it increment for each image.

I have tried variations on the below without success:

```
exiftool(-SerialNumber+=001-001-0001-0001)
exiftool(-SerialNumber+='001-001-0001-0001')
```

I realize most likely ExifTool is seeing these as numbers being subtracted in the first line and seeing the second line as a string.  I have also tried:

```
exiftool(-SerialNumber+='1')
exiftool(-SerialNumber+=1)
```

just to see if I can even get it to increment with a basic, single digit number.  This also has not worked.

Maybe this cannot be incremented this way and I need to use ExifTool from the command line.  If so, I am learning the command line/powershell (Windows), but am still weak in this area and would appreciate some pointers to get started there if this is the route I need to take.  I am not afraid to use the command line, just would need a bit more hand holding then normal for a starting point.  I also am learning Linux and could do this project from there but again, not afraid to use it, just would need a bit more hand holding to get it done.

I do program in PHP, JavaScript and other languages so code is not foreign to me.  Just experience in writing it for the command-line.

If further clarification is needed, please let me know in the comments.

Your help and guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to go to the command line rather than rely upon drag and drop as this command relies upon ExifTool's advance formatting.

`Exiftool "-SerialNumber<001-001-0001-${filesequence;$_=sprintf('%04d', $_+1 )}" <FILE/DIR>`

If you want to be more general purpose and to use the original serial number in the file, you could use

`Exiftool "-SerialNumber<${SerialNumber}-${filesequence;$_=sprintf('%04d', $_+1 )}" <FILE/DIR>`

This will just add the file count to the end of the current serial number in the image, though if you have images from multiple cameras in the same directory, that could get messy.

As for using the command line, you just need to rename to remove the commands in the parens and then either move it to someplace in the command line's path or use the full path to ExifTool.

As for clarification on your previous attempts, the `+=` option is used with numbers and with lists.  The SerialNumber tag is usually a string, though that could depend upon where it's being written to.

Comment: I ran it from the command line, but nothing happened with the serial number.  It remained the same.  Below is the exact command I ran.  ExifTool.exe is in the TIFF directory as are 16 test images.  After it runs, it says "1 directories scanned" and "16 image files updated". 

exiftool "-SerialNumber<001-001-0001-${filesequence;$_=sprintf('%04d', $_+1 )}" c:\TIFF

Comment: Hmmm, strange.  I tried it here on some tiffs and it worked fine.  What are you using to read the serial numbers?  Try using `ExifTool -a -G1 -serialnumber` on one of the files and seeing if there is more than one serial number tag.  One possible problem I see is that some MakerNotes serial number tags, like Canon, must be a number, not a string, and won't be changed by this.  But SerialNumber tags in Exif and XMP (there isn't an IPTC SerialNumber tag) as well as Nikon and Leica MakerNotes should be changed correctly.

Comment: Completely embarrassed to say I was looking at the master files after running the command you provided.  When I pulled my head out and actually looked at the test folder the serial number has indeed populated and incremented properly.  You rock and sorry for wasting your time!  :-)

Comment: Exiftool is not case sensitive on the tag names.  Sorry about IPTC confusion.  IPTCcore is technically XMP and I was talking about legacy IPTC.  I don't have Bridge but when I check with Lightroom 4.4, Job Identifier translates to the TransmissionReference tag.

Comment: Heh, been there, done that way too many times. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: If I could trouble you for one more item.  I think I understand the sprintf format to be adding 4 numbers at the end and incrementing by one.  Which is great for my first batch.  When I run subsequent batches, how can I define the starting number (i.e. where I left of from the previous batch in my number sequence)?  I tried looking up the formatting for sprintf but can't find it anywhere except PHP and I'm sure this is not PHP we are working with here.  :-)  Thank you!

Comment: tl;dr:  Just change `$_+1` to `$_+NewStartingNumber`.   The sprintf just pads the number with leading zeroes and doesn't do any incrementing.  The key to this is the FileSequence tag.  This is a tag internal to ExifTool and keeps track of the number of files it processes in a run.  It starts with zero and due to the nature of the advanced formatting (basically running some perl commands), the `$_` variable has this number assigned to it.  Since you wanted to start with 1, I just added 1 to the variable.  To start at a different number, just add that number to `$_`.

Comment: Makes sense completely.  I just incorrectly assumed $_+1 was the increment count.  Thanks so much!  I did start this as a new question, so if you want to pop over there and post an answer, great.  If not, just let me know so I can answer it and close it out.  Thanks again!  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924158/how-to-set-starting-number-for-exiftool-serialnumber-change

Comment: Tried to answer other post with link to my comment here, but it was changed to comment.  I'd say just go ahead and close it.

Comment: I removed the other question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this should work:

```psh
1..100 | % {
  $sn = '811-010-5469-{0:D4}' -f $_

  # apply $sn
}
```

or like this (if you iterate over files):

```psh
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem 'C:\some\folder' -File | % {
  $sn = '811-010-5469-{0:D4}' -f $i

  # update EXIF data of current file with $sn

  $i++
}
```